# How to set a default to a forms.ChoiceField()?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set a default selection for payment choices to be Stripe, but I keep getting an error`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'`

Here is the forms.py

```
PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Stripe'),
    ('P', 'Paypal')
)

class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    payment_option = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default='Stripe')
```

Answer (score 3):

At first, `form.*Field` classes has no `default` attribute. However, it has `initial` attribute represents a value which will be displayed after rendering a page.

Also in `PAYMENT_CHOICES` you should use in your code first values of tuples since these tuples contain real value in first place and verbose name in second.

That is how working version of your code may looks:

```py
PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Stripe'),
    ('P', 'Paypal')
)

class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    payment_option = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES,
        initial='S')
```

Comment: Hi I added it but it does not this make it a default, if no selection by the user took place does it auto selects the 's' ?

Comment: No, it only declares initial value of html `<select>`. If you want to always save `'S'` when the  user selected empty value, you can redefine `clean` methods of your Form or use signal handlers.